# rewrting feed_dict tf.session and tf.graph to estimator

Tags: google-cloud-tpu

I have some code which was written with the feed_dict to tf.Session and tf.Graph low level API and since I want to use it on a TPU I am trying to rewrite it into tf.Estimator API

Below is the current version of the code. (some fragments are removed for brevity and marked as ...)

```
class my_tpu_class(object):

def __init__(self, ):
    // ...code to initialize class members
    self.g = tf.Graph()
    self._buildGraph()
    self.session = tf.Session(graph = self.g)

def _buildGraph(self):
    with self.g.as_default():
        XPH = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, self.inputShape[0], self.inputShape[1], self.inputShape[2]], name='XPH')
        self.XPH = XPH
        YPH = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, self.outputShape1[0] + self.outputShape2[0] + self.outputShape3[0] + self.outputShape4[0]], name='YPH')
        self.YPH = YPH

        conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=XPH,
                                 filters=self.numFeature1,
                                 activation=selu.selu,
                                 name='conv1')
        self.conv1 = conv1

       // ...rest of code to build the network and get the loss.

        loss1 = tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(YBaseChangeSigmoid - tf.slice(YPH,[0,0],[-1,self.outputShape1[0]], name='YBaseChangeGetTruth'), 2, name='YBaseChangeMSE'), name='YBaseChangeReduceSum')

        loss = loss1 + other losses...
        self.loss = loss

        tf.summary.scalar("loss", loss)
        self.merged_summary_op = tf.summary.merge_all()

        self.training_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learningRatePH).minimize(loss)
        self.init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()

def init(self):
    self.session.run( self.init_op )

def close(self):
    self.session.close()

def train(self, batchX, batchY):
    loss, _, summary = self.session.run( (self.loss, self.training_op, self.merged_summary_op),
                                          feed_dict={self.XPH:batchX, self.YPH:batchY, self.learningRatePH:self.learningRateVal,
                                          self.phasePH:True, self.dropoutRatePH:self.dropoutRateVal})
    return loss, summary
```

I read through most of the estimator and tensorflow documentation and was able to come up with the below version using estimator interface.

```
class my_tpu_class(object):

def __init__(self, ):
    //...code to initialize class members

def my_model_fn(self, XPH, YPH, mode, params): 
        conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=XPH,
                                 filters=self.numFeature1,
                                 activation=selu.selu,
                                 name='conv1')
        self.conv1 = conv1

        // rest of code to build the network and get the loss....

        loss1 = tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(YBaseChangeSigmoid - tf.slice(YPH,[0,0],[-1,self.outputShape1[0]], name='YBaseChangeGetTruth'), 2, name='YBaseChangeMSE'), name='YBaseChangeReduceSum')

        loss = loss1 + other losses....
        self.loss = loss

        tf.summary.scalar("loss", loss)
        self.merged_summary_op = tf.summary.merge_all()

        self.training_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=params['learningRatePH']).minimize(loss)
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, loss=self.loss, train_op=self.training_op, eval_metric_ops=self.merged_summary_op)

def init(self):
    print ("No op")

def close(self):
    self.session.close()

def train_input_fn(self, features, labels):
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((features, labels))
    return dataset.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()

def train(self, batchX, batchY):
    my_tpu_estimator = tf.estimator.Estimator( model_fn=self.my_model_fn, 
                                               params= {'learningRatePH':self.learningRateVal, 'phasePH':True, 'dropoutRatePH':self.dropoutRateVal })
    my_tpu_estimator.train(input_fn=self.train_input_fn(batchX, batchY))
```

Is this the right way to do this or have understood the estimator concepts incorrectly? For now the app crashes in the train function call. So I guess I have got something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The code that you have written is not the TPU one. It is just using Estimator API which is a high level API. 
As per me it should be working on CPU or GPU, but not on TPU.
For TPU, you should be using TPUEstimator API.

In order to figure out the exact cause of crash, I want to know that if you are running this on TPU or CPU. Also could you please copy-paste the console error coming during crash.